# Rails 3: Paypal Adaptive Payments (ActiveMerchant?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal

I've been searching high and low for the best solution to this: making paypal adaptive payments (specifically, chained payments) through rails 3.  I found activemerchant, but I don't think any of the adaptive payments additions work with rails 3.  It wasn't clear from their documentation, if they had any.

ActiveMerchant sounds like it would be an ideal solution, because we hope to move beyond paypal eventually.  However, I'm open to other options--especially fast, easy, and well-documented solutions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at Tommy's paypal_adaptive gem? I've had good luck using it for 1 recipient payments. It should also be able to support chained payments.

https://github.com/tc/paypal_adaptive

Unfortunately it doesn't support the embedded payments that keep the user experience on your site while registering with PayPal.

If you have trouble you can enable debug info in request.rb and ipn_notification.rb.

http.set_debug_output($stdout)

Installation instructions: http://tommy.chheng.com/index.php/2009/12/paypal-adaptive-ruby-gem-released/

Comment: Thanks, this is one option I was considering, but I was hoping someone would have some experience with using adaptive payments and activemerchant (or something similar) because we plan on moving away from paypal once our project matures.  I may just have to implement two separate solutions.  : P

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [the active_paypal_adaptive_payment gem](https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment) based off [Active Merchant](https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant). It works pretty well.

Comment: cool thanks, it looks like it's based off of tommy's gem and some other stuff